# Create and match tuples from an input text file and extract the matching tuples by comparing two text files

Tags: python

I have a text file with a list of string pairs such as

string1, string2

string3, string4

I can create a look-up table for this list.

I have another text file which has all these strings (not pairwise, but in a single column with a value assigned for each string)

For example,

string1, 9

string2, 8

string4, 5

string3, 2

I want to get an output file with the following:

string1, 9, string2, 8

string3, 2, string4, 5

provided these pair of strings exist as a pair in the first text file.

I tried this code, but it is only giving me one single pair.

```py
m1 = open('String_Pairs.txt')
m2 = open('String_Scores.txt')
output = open('Output_Pairs_Scores.txt','w')


lookup_from = {}
l=[]

for line1 in m2:
    x1 = line1.split(',')[0].strip()
    x2 = line1.split(',')[1].strip()
    XX = (x1,x2)
    lookup_from[XX] = 0

for line3 in m1:
    z1 = line3.split(',')[0].strip()
    z2 = line3.split(',')[1].strip()
    for line3 in m1:
        z11 = line3.split(',')[0].strip()
        z22 = line3.split(',')[1].strip()
        if (z1,z11) in lookup_from:
            k1 = (z1,z11)
            k2 = (z2,z22)
            z1 = k1 + k2
            l.append(z1)
            print(l)

for i in l:
    output.write(str(i)[1:-1]+'\n')
output.close()
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code gives the exact output you are after, however I much prefer Grismar's answer

```
dic={}

with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        dic.update({line.replace('\n','').split(',')[0]:line.replace('\n','').split(',')[1]})

out = open('out.txt','w')
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        tmp=line.replace('\n','').split(',')[0]
        tmp1=line.replace('\n','').replace(' ','').split(',')[1]
        out.write(' '.join([tmp.replace(tmp,tmp+','+dic[tmp]),',',tmp1.replace(tmp1,tmp1+','+dic[tmp1]),'\n']))

out.close()
```

EDIT - for the record file includes the scores (i.e. string1,9) and file1 includes the strings ('string1, string2')

```
dic={}

with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line != '\n':
            dic.update({line.replace('\n','').split(',')[0]:line.replace('\n','').split(',')[1]})

out = open('out.txt','w')
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        if line != '\n':
            tmp=line.replace('\n','').split(',')[0]
            tmp1=line.replace('\n','').replace(' ','').split(',')[1]
            out.write(' '.join([tmp.replace(tmp,tmp+','+dic[tmp]),',',tmp1.replace(tmp1,tmp1+','+dic[tmp1]),'\n\n']))

out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is giving me "KeyError:6". Could you please explain me why?

Comment: not 100% sure, I copied your example text into .txt files but I deleted the spacing between lines (wasn't sure if this was just the way it got pasted into the OP), but see above edit to run on .txt files if there are actually spaces between lines...copied your example text directly and it runs for me

Comment: maybe run it line by line and see where the error occurs, might just be some format issue with the way your file is/the way I've attempted to parse them that can be fixed with a slight tweak

Answer (score 0):

In general, break down the problem and turn each smaller problem into a Python problem. Your first file is really just a list of strings. Your second file is really just a dictionary you want to use for lookup. And the file you want to write is a list of tuples (although it looks like you want to write it as a single list). Each of the tuples matches a string from the first list, paired with the lookup value from the dictionary.

Coding those steps:

```py
with open('String_Pairs.txt') as pf:
    # assuming all the data is on the first line
    pairs = [p.strip() for p in next(pf).split(',')]

with open('String_Scores.txt') as sf:
    lookup = {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in [line.split(',') for line in sf]}

with open('Output_Pairs_Scores.txt','w') as of:
    of.write(','.join([f'{key},{lookup[key]}' for key in pairs]))
```

That's all the code you need.

As for why your code doesn't work: you're looping through `m1`, inside the loop that's looping through `m1` - that won't work. Here:

```
for line3 in m1:
    z1 = line3.split(',')[0].strip()
    z2 = line3.split(',')[1].strip()
    for line3 in m1:
        ...
```

Your lookup is a `dict`, but you're only using its keys, that's not how you should do it, instead do something like:

```
lookup_from[x1] = x2
```

I didn't go into the rest of the code, since it breaks in multiple places. Feel free to try and piece together why my example works, or perhaps come back with a version of your solution if you have remaining problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to clarify something here. The first file has pairs such as line1: string1,string2, line2: string3,string5 etc. The second file has lines of the form line1: string1, 9 line2: string2, 9, line3: string3, 2 line4: string5, 6 etc. I want to make pairs from the second list which match with the first list pairs. In addition I also want to carry the score that each string has from the second list while making these pairs. For example, the output would be line1: string1, 9, string2, 8, line2:  string3,2, string5,6